# Select2 in Knockout.Js with custom template

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, jquery-select2

I want to use select2 in knockout.js

for this i have a bindinghandler.

```
ko.bindingHandlers.select2 = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
        var obj = valueAccessor(),
            allBindings = allBindingsAccessor(),
            lookupKey = allBindings.lookupKey;
        $(element).select2(obj);
        if (lookupKey) {
            var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(allBindings.value);
            $(element).select2('data', ko.utils.arrayFirst(obj.data.results, function(item) {
                return item[lookupKey] === value;
            }));
        }

        ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.addDisposeCallback(element, function() {
            $(element).select2('destroy');
        });
    },
    update: function(element) {
        $(element).trigger('change');
    }
};
```

i use the handler like this:

```
 <select id="itemselector" data-bind="options: items, optionsText: 'Name', OptionsValue:'Id', select2: {}"></select>
```

now to make custom templates i have to pass a format function to select2 like htis

```
 function formatSelection(item) {
          return '<b>' + item.text + '</b>';
        }
```

but i can't figure out how to do this with that binding handle. Can someone explain me how to pass the formatfunction or a string template to the binding handler, so that it will be applied to select?

Comment: I think you forgot to include the bit where you use the handler (you say "like this:" with nothing there).

Comment: yeah sorry i added it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add your option(s) into the `{}` after the select2 binding declaration. For example:

```html
 <select id="itemselector" data-bind="options: items, optionsText: 'Name', optionsValue:'Id', select2: {formatResult: formatSelection}"></select>
```

Question back at you, the select2 binding that you are using, is a new version to me. How is the `lookupKey` being used?